# How do i make all my content centered in html

Tags: html, css

I started making a page for my web design class and i ran into a problem. My page has a navigation bar and a picture so far. i wanted to center them both using css.

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

I used this for both my nav bar and my img. I want the nav bar to always be above the image even if the page gets resized. is there anyway to do this in css?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: `selector { text-align: center }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins will center if the element has a width.
So your css might look like:

```
img{
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav{
    width:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

basic html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Something</li>
        <li>Something else</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<img src="../path-to-file.jpg" alt="image">
```

That would center both elements.

As for making the nav always above the image... do you mean like overlapping it? Or just "above" it the way your question is above this answer?

I can update this post if you make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "I want the nav bar to always be above the image even if the page gets resized. is there anyway to do this in css?"

Use z-index property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

If you want the navbar to stick to the top use `position: absolute`